# How to make ref to component and listen for click outside?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i'm trying to make dropdown option component. I want to show it by clicking on the button, and hide it if click was detected outside of this component.

Here is a code. I made ref, but i cant understand how to check if click was on component or not:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './OptionsMenu.sass'

import DropdownBox from '../DropdownBox/DropdownBox'
import Icon from '../Icon/Icon'

class OptionsMenu extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.dropdownBoxRef = React.createRef()
    }

  handleClickOutside = event => {
    if (this.dropdownBoxRef && !this.dropdownBoxRef.contains(event.target)) {
      this.props.close()
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.handleClickOutside)
  }

  render() {
    const options = this.props.options.map(option => (
      <li className='OptionsList-Element'>
        <div className='OptionsList-ElementIcon'>
          <Icon name={option.icon} />
        </div>
        <span>{option.label}</span>
      </li>
    ))
    return (
      <DropdownBox ref={this.dropdownBoxRef} styles={this.props.styles}>
        <ul className='OptionsList'>{options}</ul>
      </DropdownBox>
    )
  }
}

export default OptionsMenu
```

With this code i have error: 
**OptionsMenu.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: _this.dropdownBoxRef.contains is not a function**

I know the error, cause it has not .contains(). So what to i must try to use?

Comment: Would you mind also providing the code of the `DropdownBox` component?

Comment: You need an `isVisible` state for your `Dropdown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the updated code that helps to solve your issue:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class OptionsMenu extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.dropdownBoxRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleClickOutside = event => {
    if (this.dropdownBoxRef && !this.dropdownBoxRef.current.contains(event.target)) {
      this.props.close();
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this.handleClickOutside);
  }

  render() {
    const options = ["a", "b", "c"].map(option => (
      <li className="OptionsList-Element">
        <div className="OptionsList-ElementIcon">Icon</div>
        <span>{option.label}</span>
      </li>
    ));
    return (
      <div ref={this.dropdownBoxRef} styles={this.props.styles}>
        <ul className="OptionsList">{options}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default OptionsMenu;

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<OptionsMenu />, rootElement);
```

Note: this.dropdownBoxRef.current.contains(event.target) line is the game changer.

Comment: Thanks with your solution! i think this will help, but now i have different issue. I have this warning `Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?`, thats becasue my dropdown box component is functional. Can you help to fix issue, without switching it to class based

Comment: @WhoIsDT: Try changing Functional Component (DropdownBox ) to Class Component. I hope it will resolve your problem.

Comment: @WhoIsDT try to wrap div on your functional component and move ref from functional component to wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

Refs have things stored inside a property called `current`. So in order to actually reach your element you'll have to do `this.dropdownBoxRef.current` and call `.contains` on that.